# Tabs that load before the internal tabs causes an error "The value provided to the Tabs component is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I use a tabs element of material-UI, but the tabs itself I receive from props.
the first tab with the value 0, I want to be chosen.

Here my code:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ChannelContext } from '../context/channelContext'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

export default function Channels(props) {
  let channelsList = []
  props.channels.forEach((elem,i) => {
    channelsList.push( <Tab key={i} label={elem.channel_name} value={elem.server_id-1} />)
  })

  const [, setchannelBanner] = useContext(ChannelContext)
  const [channelId, setChannelId] = React.useState(0); 

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setChannelId(newValue)
    setchannelBanner(props.channels[newValue].bg_image);
  };

  return (
        <AppBar position="static" color="inherit" elevation={0}>
        <Tabs 
          value={channelId}
          onChange={handleChange} 
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="auto"
          aria-label="scrollable auto tabs" className="tabs">
          {channelsList}
        </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
  );
}
```

I receive this error on the browser console:

```
"Material-UI: The value provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
None of the Tabs' children match with `0`.
You can provide one of the following values: NaN."
```

if i change the React.useState(0) to React.useState(false) or React.useState(NaN), the error disappear but the first tab not choosen.
I understand that it's happening because the main Tabs element loads before the internal tabs array.
How do you suggest resolving it?

Comment: Can you please share the code sandbox link with this code? It'd be much easier to edit/debug things there.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving it would be to use useEffect and change the state from NaN to 0 when the main tabs are loaded.
It would be better if you can share a link to code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is to use useEffect on props and then inside the useEffect check if the first element/channel exists, only then make the setChannelId(0).

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ChannelContext } from '../context/channelContext'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

export default function Channels(props) {
  const [, setchannelBanner] = useContext(ChannelContext)
  const [channelId, setChannelId] = React.useState(false); 

  // setChannelId after tabs are loaded
  useEffect(() => {
    if( props.channels[0].server_id >= 0 ) setChannelId(0)
  }, [props]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setChannelId(newValue)
    setchannelBanner(props.channels[newValue].bg_image);
  };

  return (
        <AppBar position="static" color="inherit" elevation={0}>
          <Tabs 
            value={channelId}
            onChange={handleChange} 
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
            aria-label="scrollable auto tabs" className="tabs">
            {props.channels.map((elem,i) => (
              <Tab key={i} label={elem.channel_name} value={elem.server_id-1}/>
            ))}
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
  );
}
```